# Component on glass area

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-xe2, aero-glass

How do I put a control (button, panel, pagecontrol, label) in the glass area of a windows form?

[image: control in glass area]

Thanks!

Comment: There's a similar question with answers [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364648/delphi-button-on-glass-best-looking-third-party-button-component

Comment: See this article by Chris Rolliston, [setting-up-a-custom-titlebar](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/) and study this component by Paul Thornton, [TChromeTabs](http://www.easy-ip.net/tchrometabs.html).

Comment: @LU RD - I think the OP wants to draw in the title bar, not just draw on glass. Currently, TChromeTabs won't help him much as it can't yet draw the tabs in the title area. Hopefully it will soon though :)

Comment: @norgepaul, your component really looks nice, good news that it soon can be fit into the title area.

Comment: @LU RD - Thanks for the kind words :)

Comment: Keep in mind that applications such as this are using Microsoft's Ribbon control, which is actually a licensed product and is available in later versions of Delphi. It automatically draws in the title section exactly as the application above (which in fact is using the ribbon control)

Comment: @LU RD - TChromeTabs now supports drawing the tabs in the title bar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chris Rolliston explains how to do this in his article: http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/22/setting-up-a-custom-title-bar-reprise/.

A demo project can be downloaded here: http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/27688

Comment: I've just implemented the title bar tab functionality in TChromeTabs. If you grab the latest code from subversion you can see how I did it. Look at ChromeTabsGlassForm.pas.