# How do I create a window with different Aero glass frame?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, coding-style, window, aero-glass

I think there is a customized window style in `Windows 7`. like this :

[image]
[image]

And as you can see it's different from normal style :

[image]

How can i create a window with the style that you can see in the first picture ?

Comment: I expect you are going to need DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea and some custom painting. I've no experience of this myself (as is well documented, I'm a plain vanilla kind of guy). This well known article covers non-client painting on glass: http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/

Comment: What are you asking for? Do you mean that the Windows theme color is ignored and the window caption is not transparent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What Delphi version? Delphi 2010 can do this natively:

[image]

You just have to play with the `GlassFrame` property of the form. You might also want to read my answer here, and make sure you also read the comments: [Delphi support for Aero Glass and the DoubleBuffered property - what is going on and how do we use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357224/delphi-support-for-aero-glass-and-the-doublebuffered-property-what-is-going-on/3364941#3364941)

Comment: @Kermia, if you're talking about my "Delphi 2010 can do this natively" image, there's no code behind it: It's just a form on Delphi 2010 with `GlassFrame.Enabled` = `True` and `GlassFrame.Top` = `120`.

Comment: @Johan, anti-aliased text and color-keying don't work well together, not to mention the color-key is *black*. For The Brave, I'm guessing the proper way to do this is using [UpdateLayeredWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633556(v=vs.85).aspx), but I've once been there and it's a world of pain. Because layered windows don't like user input.

Comment: Oh OK . Is it possible to set a shadow for controls that placed in glass-frameed window ?

Comment: No, there's no automatic way to give controls a shadow; But you could place a shadow-like semi-transparent image behind the control to simulate that.

Answer (score 5):

those things are done with glass composition color.

take a look here: [Changing the glass composition color (DWM) using delphi](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/category/dwm/)

Comment: I was in the middle of typing something similar. <g> You're just a little faster. +1. You might want to edit to mention that in D2009-XE you can just click on the form and then set the `GlassFrame.Enabled` property to true in the Object Inspector to achieve much of this immediately.

Comment: **Beware,** the undocumented DWM function mentioned in the blog post changes the composition color **system wide** and **persistently**. It stays changed even after a reboot!